# django - inlineformset_factory with more than one ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do a formset with the following models (boost is the primary):

```
class boost(models.Model):
   creator = models.ForeignKey(userInfo)
   game  = models.ForeignKey(gameInfo)
   name  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   desc  = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   rules = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   subscribe = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class userInfo(models.Model):
   pic_url= models.URLField(default=0, blank=True)
   auth   = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
   birth  = models.DateTimeField(default=0, blank=True)
   country= models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

class gameInfo(models.Model):
   psn_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   name   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   publisher = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=0)
   developer = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=0)
   release_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to display a form to add a Boost item, trying to do in this way :

```
TrophyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(db.gameInfo, db.boost, extra=1)
formset = TrophyFormSet()
```

Here are my questions :

1 - When rendered, the combo box for "Creator" shows a list of "db.userInfo" (literally)! I want this to display db.userInfo.auth.username that is already in the database... how to do this?

2 - In this way, where is my "db.gameInfo" to choose?

thank you! =D

======

czarchaic answered my question very well!
But now I need just a little question:

When I use the modelform to create a form for the boost_trophy model :

```
class boost_trophy(models.Model):
   boost  = models.ForeignKey(boost)
   trophy = models.ForeignKey(gameTrophyInfo)
   # 0 - Obtiveis
   # 1 - Requisitos minimos
   type   = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class gameTrophyInfo(models.Model):
   game = models.ForeignKey(gameInfo)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

It works nice, but I want the form to show in the "game" box only a really small set of items, only the: gameTrophyInfo(game__name="Game_A") results. How can I do this?

Comment: That should be the effect.  each gameTrophyInfo can belong to one gameInfo, but each gameInfo can have multiple gameTrophyInfos

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

To change what is displayed set the model's  `__unicode__` function

```
class userInfo(models.Model):
  #model fields

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.auth.username
```

Comment: put what you said, both in gameInfo and userInfo.
with gameInfo is ok, thanks ! but with userInfo, i get a error :

User matching query does not exist.

is this why the self.auth.username is in another model ?

Comment: @fabriciols have you used `prefecth_related` yet?